# trying to do a menu loop

Tags: c#, loops, menu

I'm teaching myself C# in visual studio and trying to add a loop to my code so it works like a menu where a user can select an option but exit that option at any time without having to stop and restart the whole code. I just cant figure out where to put it so that it runs properly - the rest of the code works like a menu but only lets you select one option and run it one time before stopping.

This is what I have so far;

---

class Program
{
private static string membership;

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Gym Menu";
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome,  What would you like to do?");
        Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("[1] BMI Calculator");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] Choose Membership");
        Console.WriteLine("[3] Exit");

            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input == "1")
            {
            bmicalculator();
            }
            else if (input == "2")
            {
            choosemembership();
            }

            else if (input == "3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("goodbye");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        public static void mainmenu()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void bmicalculator()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BMI Calculator");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Weight in kg: ");
            int kg; kg = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Height in cm: ");
            int m; m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            double BMI; BMI = kg / ((m / 100.0) * (m / 100.0));
            Console.WriteLine("your BMI is.." + BMI);
            if (BMI < 18.5) { Console.WriteLine("-> Underweight"); }
            if (BMI >= 18.5 & BMI <= 25) { Console.WriteLine("-> Normal"); }
            if (BMI >= 25 & BMI <= 30) { Console.WriteLine("-> Overweight"); }
            if (BMI >= 30) { Console.WriteLine("-> Obese"); }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue or enter return to go to the menu..");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.ReadLine();

        }
        public static void choosemembership()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose your membership from the options below");
            Console.WriteLine(" Basic $10pw - Regular $15pw -  Premium $20pw");
            membership = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (membership)
            {
                case "Basic":
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the basic membership for $10 per week");
                        break;
                    }
                case "Regular":
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the regular membership for $15 per week");
                        break;
                    }
                case "Premium":
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the premium membership for $20 per week");
                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have not selected a valid membership type");
                        break;
                    }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

}
```

---

if anyone can help I would appreciate it :)

Comment: You need to study what loops are and how they work. Here a sample tutorial https://www.w3schools.in/csharp-tutorial/loops/

Comment: Hi, thanks for this link! im trying to study it through a polytechnic but their course is very badly designed and I have been struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, Note that there is one line of code I commented it out.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Title = "Gym Menu";
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome,  What would you like to do?");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("[1] BMI Calculator");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] Choose Membership");
            Console.WriteLine("[3] Exit");

            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input == "1")
            {
                bmicalculator();
            }
            else if (input == "2")
            {
                choosemembership();
            }

            else if (input == "3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("goodbye");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        };
        
    }

    public static void mainmenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void bmicalculator()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BMI Calculator");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Weight in kg: ");
        int kg; kg = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Height in cm: ");
        int m; m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        double BMI; BMI = kg / ((m / 100.0) * (m / 100.0));
        Console.WriteLine("your BMI is.." + BMI);
        if (BMI < 18.5) { Console.WriteLine("-> Underweight"); }
        if (BMI >= 18.5 & BMI <= 25) { Console.WriteLine("-> Normal"); }
        if (BMI >= 25 & BMI <= 30) { Console.WriteLine("-> Overweight"); }
        if (BMI >= 30) { Console.WriteLine("-> Obese"); }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue or enter return to go to the menu..");
        Console.ReadKey();
        // Console.ReadLine();

    }
    public static void choosemembership()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose your membership from the options below");
        Console.WriteLine(" Basic $10pw - Regular $15pw -  Premium $20pw");
        var membership = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (membership)
        {
            case "Basic":
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the basic membership for $10 per week");
                    break;
                }
            case "Regular":
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the regular membership for $15 per week");
                    break;
                }
            case "Premium":
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the premium membership for $20 per week");
                    break;
                }

            default:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have not selected a valid membership type");
                    break;
                }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

do a while loop immediately inside the main function...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        .... existing code as is
    }
{
```